# Install4j java opt "i4jv"

Tags: java, install4j

What is the install4j java option "i4jv" as in "-Di4jv=0" for/mean? I ran across multiple in SmartBear Collaborator process listing and was wondering what it signifies. Thanks for any insight as Google isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is a technical detail related to entries in .vmoptions files that have spaces in their value.